Why is my accuracy fluctuating for a while and then stuck?
I am building a cnn classifying model to predict images over 3 classes. The data is balanced, with 10.5k images for train ( 3.5k for each ), 3k validation images ( 1k each ).
I increased my validation accuracy at around 70%-75% but can't go further
I used tuner to search for optimal hyperparameters, but the best I got from it is this model:
def build_model():
    """Builds a convolutional model."""

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(80, 80, 3)),
      tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255)
    ])
   # 1st - filters 1 = 48
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
            filters=48,
            kernel_size=4,
            padding="same",
        ))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.1))

    # 2nd - filters 192, kernel 4, pooling max, no dropout
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
            filters=192,
            kernel_size=4,
            padding="same",
        ))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU())


    #3rd - filters: 64, kernel - 5, maxpool dropout = 0.3
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
            filters=256,
            kernel_size=5,
            padding="same",
        ))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.1))
    # global avg pooling
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
    # flatten - no hyperparametr
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    # dense layers: 2, NO REGULARIZERS
    # 1st layer: 288 units
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=288))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
       

    # 2nd dense: 192, 0.3 dropout, no regulraizers!!
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=192))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.3))

    # add last dense layer for num_classes:
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax'))

    lr = 0.0010297

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)
    model.compile(
        optimizer, loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"]
    )

    return model

This resulted in around 0.73 val_accuracy, with no data_augumentation at all. The thing is that after getting to 0.7, both training and val were stuck there, pretty stable, not going further, not decreasing.
So I tried modifying the learning rate to use Cosine decay, switching to SGD as an optimizer, and trying some data_augumentation processes, and also making the model more complex so that the training_accuracy will grow more.
I came up with two of what I think are closest to a better model, even though the val_accuracy didn't increase:
For both of them, this was the cosine_decay lr scheduler and optimizer:
def lr_warmup_cosine_decay(
    global_step,
    warmup_steps,
    hold=0,
    total_steps=0,
    start_lr=0.0,
    target_lr=1e-2,
):
    # Cosine decay
    learning_rate = (
        0.5
        * target_lr
        * (
            1
            + ops.cos(
                math.pi
                * ops.convert_to_tensor(
                    global_step - warmup_steps - hold, dtype="float32"
                )
                / ops.convert_to_tensor(
                    total_steps - warmup_steps - hold, dtype="float32"
                )
            )
        )
    )

    warmup_lr = target_lr * (global_step / warmup_steps)

    if hold > 0:
        learning_rate = ops.where(
            global_step > warmup_steps + hold, learning_rate, target_lr
        )

    learning_rate = ops.where(global_step < warmup_steps, warmup_lr, learning_rate)
    return learning_rate


class WarmUpCosineDecay(schedules.LearningRateSchedule):
    def __init__(self, warmup_steps, total_steps, hold, start_lr=0.0, target_lr=1e-2):
        super().__init__()
        self.start_lr = start_lr
        self.target_lr = target_lr
        self.warmup_steps = warmup_steps
        self.total_steps = total_steps
        self.hold = hold

    def __call__(self, step):
        lr = lr_warmup_cosine_decay(
            global_step=step,
            total_steps=self.total_steps,
            warmup_steps=self.warmup_steps,
            start_lr=self.start_lr,
            target_lr=self.target_lr,
            hold=self.hold,
        )

        return ops.where(step > self.total_steps, 0.0, lr)

optimizer:
total_images = 10500
total_steps = (total_images // BATCH_SIZE) * EPOCHS
warmup_steps = int(0.1 * total_steps)
hold_steps = int(0.45 * total_steps)
schedule = WarmUpCosineDecay(
    start_lr=0.05,
    target_lr=1e-2,
    warmup_steps=warmup_steps,
    total_steps=total_steps,
    hold=hold_steps,
)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(
    weight_decay=5e-4,
    learning_rate=schedule,
    momentum=0.9,
)

1. No data augumentation, one more dense layer and no kernel_regularization
same model just repeat the 1st dense layer, with no dropout
# 0.73 val_accuracy, while training_accuracy went up to 0.9 for 40epochs

2. No data augumentation, one more dense layer and kernel_regularization=L2(0.01)
same as the first, just added kernel_regularization=L2(0.01) to the dense layers
# around 0.75 val_accuracy, while training_accuracy went up to 0.98 for 40epochs

So I saw this as an overfit and try to tweak the training data via some data_augmentation processes. At first I overshoot it, with too much augments, like this:
# simple random flip
random_flip = keras_cv.layers.RandomFlip()
augmenters = [random_flip]

# crop + resize
crop_and_resize = keras_cv.layers.RandomCropAndResize(
    target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
    crop_area_factor=(0.8, 1.0),
    aspect_ratio_factor=(0.9, 1.1),
)
augmenters += [crop_and_resize]


# adding random augumentations
rand_augment = keras_cv.layers.RandAugment(
    augmentations_per_image=3,
    value_range=(0, 255),
    magnitude=0.3,
    magnitude_stddev=0.2,
    rate=0.7,
)
augmenters += [rand_augment]


# adding random choice between cutmix and mixup
cut_mix = keras_cv.layers.CutMix()
mix_up = keras_cv.layers.MixUp()


cut_mix_or_mix_up = keras_cv.layers.RandomChoice([cut_mix, mix_up], batchwise=True)
augmenters += [cut_mix_or_mix_up]

But this didn't help either. My val_accuracy is fluctuating for a while, and stabilizing at the end, by the 90th epoch. ( i'm running a total of 100 epochs)
Confusion Matrix for the model:

accuracy/loss curves:

epoch history

fluctuating


stabilized at the end



What should I do further? It seems like I'm somehow stuck between a stable model with maximum capacity of 0.7, and two overfitting models with a 0.7 validation accuracy at best
